# Orthogonality of Bessel function

Tags: functional-analysis, bessel-functions, sturm-liouville

I was studying some properties of regular Sturm-Liouville problems. I have seen that (given proper boundary conditions) given the problem

$$L(f)+ \lambda \omega f=0$$

With $L(f)=(rf')'+pf$ and $\omega, r,p $ regular real valued functions (not being too formal, sorry), then there are some properties which are satisfied. For instance, $\lambda$ is real and two eigenfunctions are orthogonal with respect to the scalar product $\int f \bar{g} \omega dx$.

Now, I have seen how to write a Bessel equation $f'' + \frac{f'}{x} + \frac{x^2 - n^2}{x^2} f=0$ as a Sturm-Liouville problem, which is

$$(xf')' - \frac{n^2}{x} f + xf$$

Where $p=-\frac{n^2}{x}$ and $\omega=x$. Now, this would mean that $\int J_n (ax)J_n(bx)xdx=0$ if $a \neq b$, and I have found this result on the internet as well. But I have been told (but maybe I just got it wrong and the result above was what he was trying to explain) that also $\int J_p(x) J_q(x)xdx=0$ if $p \neq q$, where the two functions are solutions of the Bessel equation with $n$ changed by $p$ and $q$. Now, I wasn't able to put this in a Sturm-Liouville form, because changing $n$ would change $L$ and I couldn't say anything. Also, I haven't found anything on the internet. So is there a way to prove it using Sturm-Liouville (and how can I do that) or I simply got it wrong and it isn't true?

Comment: What interval are you working on?

Comment: In general we took a closed real interval $[a,b]$, I don't think we put some restrictions to $a$ or $b$, but if it is useful you can take it $[0,1]$ for instance, or maybe like $[1,2]$ if having $0$ is troublesome

Comment: Eigenfunctions that satisfy the same homogenous endpoint conditions are orthogonal with respect to the weight of the problem. The eigenvalues will depends on the conditions as well as the problem.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts but the issue is that I can't write Bessel equations of different order as a S-L problem with the same $L$. Changing $L$ would change also the border conditions, so I can't see how to prove that $\int J_p(x) J_q(x)xdx=0$, if it is true

Comment: Unless $J_p$ and $J_q$ satisfy the same endpoint conditions at $x=a$ and at $x=b$, there would be no reason to believe such orthogonality would hold.

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts now that I think about it, you are perfectly right. So in general two Bessel functions of different order are not orthogonal, because they do not satisfy proper border conditions, right?

Comment: And, if they were, they would be more likely to be orthogonal with respect to a different weight than $x$. Looks like $1/x$ would be the weight when considering $n^2$ to be the eigenvalue.